# Geometric proof of expansions of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion, euclidean-geometry

I have read that Barrow had proved the fundamental theorem of calculus. I have read that proof and its a good. Further I know Newton had derived the sine and cosine series. His methods obviously didn't contain the  'normal' calculus methods that we use today. His methods were more geometrical. Also Gregory had proved the sine and the cosine series geometrically. Has anyone read their methods or knows their approach or how they got the expansion of series geometrically. Or if anyone knows some articles or books have their methods because I have searched quite a lot on the internet without much result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be published by Newton in [De analysi per aequationes numero terminorum infinitas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_analysi_per_aequationes_numero_terminorum_infinitas) (Latin).

There is a [link](http://www.newtonproject.sussex.ac.uk/view/texts/normalized/NATP00204) to an online version.

> But just by seeing the diagrams and guessing the Latin , I don't think
>   the page covers Newton's method to derive the sine or cosine series.

Just search for 5040, you will see several instances of the sine series.

> Content
>
> The exponential series, i.e. tending toward infinity, was discovered
>   by Newton and is contained within the Analysis. The treatise contains
>   also the sine series and cosine series and arc series, the logarithmic
>   series and the binomial series.

I am not sure, if an English version will make you much happier, because not only the language of science is different from today, also the terminology and notation and the kind of reasoning is often different.

So more helpful would be a version which is translated in language and with help from an expert to bridge the difference in mathematics over this time. I am not sure if such exists for this text, put I am pretty sure such exist for part of his main works. That might give you a bit more insight.

I am pretty sure a figure like this one here

[image]

showed up in his derivation of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

From the few glances I had so far, I can not tell if he used his iteration method. (I might try again)

I put the occasional sentence through Google translate to get a better clue.

Comment: Thanks , but its not in English. I'll look if I can get a translator to translate it. But just by seeing the diagrams and guessing the Latin , I don't think the page covers Newton's method to derive the sine or cosine series. But anyways , I'll search this book.

Comment: I updated the answer in reply of the above comment.

Comment: Actually you're right. I'll try if I can get someone who can underatand it much better after translation. If you get more insight into this subject please tell or rather if possible  please explain me.

Comment: And if you can find a good version translated by an expert to cover up the differences in mathematics and notations, please tell me